# int vs IntPtr when you have a handle?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

First a background question:

In general, what is the difference between `int` and `IntPtr`?  My guess is that it is an actual object rather than a value like an `int` or `byte` is.  Assuming that is true:

So they are not the same.  Yet I see handles represented as both.

1. IntPtr: `Control.Handle`
2. int (or uint):  A PInvoke can be setup to return an `int` and it works just fine:

   ```
   [DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
   public static extern int GetForegroundWindow();
   private string GetActiveWindow()
   {
       const int nChars = 256;
       int handle = 0;
       StringBuilder Buff = new StringBuilder(nChars);

       handle = CoreDLL.GetForegroundWindow();

       if (CoreDLL.GetWindowText(handle, Buff, nChars) > 0)
       {
           return Buff.ToString();
       }

       return "";
   }
   ```

So, `int` vs `IntPtr`? Does it matter for handles?  Can you use either?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`int` is 32 bits long. `IntPtr` is as long as a pointer for your architecture. Therefore, a pointer can be stored into an `int` only on 32 bit systems, while it can *always* be stored in an `IntPtr`.

Notice that your "int as a return value" example does *not* use an `int` to hold a pointer, but just to hold a numeric value. This does not mean that an `int` is automatically the correct size though: the author of that P/Invoke signature should have gone to the documentation for [`GetForegroundWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28VS.85%29.aspx) and see that it returns a `HWND`.

Then, from `windef.h` in the Platform SDK (or [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383751%28VS.85%29.aspx)) we can see that a `HWND` is a `HANDLE` which is a `PVOID` which is... a pointer!

Therefore, as far as I can tell, that signature is *wrong*, as the size of the return value of `GetForegroundWindow` depends on the architecture. Thus, it should also be an `IntPtr`.

**Update:**

While it can be inferred from the above, I think it's worthwhile to explicitly point out that:

- Erroneously using `int` instead of `IntPtr` in 32-bit applications will never cause a problem, even if they run on 64-bit Windows; since most applications are 32-bit at this point in time, this will let you get away such mistakes very often.
- Erroneously using `int` instead of `IntPtr` in 64-bit applications is *not guaranteed* to cause problems, since it is quite possible that in practice the values being encountered will fit in the 32 bits of the `int`. This further lessens the probability that a mistake will manifest as an application error.

Therefore, for an error to actually manifest there are three conditions that have to be satisfied at the same time:

1. An `int` is used where an `IntPtr` should be.
2. The executable image is 64-bit.
3. A value returned by some PInvoke call and stored as an `int` is actually larger than 32 bits.

Comment: if you run with top down memory allocation then you can guarantee condition 3 which is very useful when developing

Comment: Your post is life-saver Jon. I wish I could do something to draw more attention into it. I had hit rock bottom with a component that was behaving erratically and your insight placed me on the right track! You made my day. No. My week. Possibly my entire month to say the least. Thanks again!

P.S.: Here's an example of how things can go south with int vs IntPtr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15548016/global-keyboard-hook/36188346#36188346

Comment: @Jon, I think that Vaccano has using this in an embedded system (may be wince, always 32 bits) [coredll.dll].